# matplotlib Line plot segment color based on flag column

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have this data:

```
sale = [10, 20, 30, 40, 43, 46, 49, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130]
season = ['Winter'] * 7 + ['Spring'] * 3 + ['Summer'] * 3 + ['Fall'] * 3
ind = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start='2020-1-1', periods=7, freq='W')),
                 pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start='2020-4-1', periods=9, freq='MS'))]).values.reshape((16,))

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Sale': sale,
    'Season': season }, 
    index=ind,
)
```

that is:

```
            Sale    Season
2020-01-05  10      Winter
2020-01-12  20      Winter
2020-01-19  30      Winter
2020-01-26  40      Winter
2020-02-02  43      Winter
2020-02-09  46      Winter
2020-02-16  49      Winter
2020-04-01  50      Spring
2020-05-01  60      Spring
2020-06-01  70      Spring
2020-07-01  80      Summer
2020-08-01  90      Summer
2020-09-01  100     Summer
2020-10-01  110     Fall
2020-11-01  120     Fall
2020-12-01  130     Fall
```

and this color map:

```
colors_map = {'Winter': 'b',
              'Spring': 'pink',
              'Summer': 'y',
              'Fall': 'orange'}
```

I can easily plot a line as below:

```
df.plot();
```

or plot a scatter plot as below:

```
plt.scatter(x=df.index, y=df['Sale'], c=df['Season'].map(colors_map))
```

**However, I do not know how to plot a line but each segment of the having a different color based on the color map**.

Here seems to be a similar question:
[Plotting multiple segments with colors based on some variable with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26726100/plotting-multiple-segments-with-colors-based-on-some-variable-with-matplotlib)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would get a single column per season to plot, which you can do with `pivot` or with `unstack`:

```
>>> sales = df.set_index('Season', append=True)['Sale']
>>> data = sales.unstack('Season')
>>> data
Season       Fall  Spring  Summer  Winter
2020-01-01    NaN     NaN     NaN    10.0
2020-02-01    NaN     NaN     NaN    20.0
2020-03-01    NaN     NaN     NaN    30.0
2020-04-01    NaN    40.0     NaN     NaN
2020-05-01    NaN    50.0     NaN     NaN
2020-06-01    NaN    60.0     NaN     NaN
2020-07-01    NaN     NaN    70.0     NaN
2020-08-01    NaN     NaN    80.0     NaN
2020-09-01    NaN     NaN    90.0     NaN
2020-10-01  100.0     NaN     NaN     NaN
2020-11-01  110.0     NaN     NaN     NaN
2020-12-01  120.0     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Call this new dataframe `data`, you can then simply plot it with:

```
data.plot(color=colors_map)
```

Here’s the result:

[image: plot results]

This gives gaps between seasons but is much much simpler than the other question you linked too.

Some options may reduce the impact of your gaps as well as really show that each “point” is in fact a whole month:

```
data.plot(color=colors_map, drawstyle='steps-pre')
```

[image: steps plot]

If that doesn’t satisfy you you’ll need to duplicate points at the boundary on 2 different columns:

First let’s select the values we’ll want to fill in, make sure the columns are in a sensible order:

```
>>> fillin = data.mask(data.isna() == data.isna().shift())
>>> fillin = fillin.reindex(['Winter', 'Spring', 'Summer', 'Fall'], axis='columns')
>>> fillin
Season      Winter  Spring  Summer   Fall
index                                    
2020-01-01    10.0     NaN     NaN    NaN
2020-02-01     NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN
2020-03-01     NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN
2020-04-01     NaN    40.0     NaN    NaN
2020-05-01     NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN
2020-06-01     NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN
2020-07-01     NaN     NaN    70.0    NaN
2020-08-01     NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN
2020-09-01     NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN
2020-10-01     NaN     NaN     NaN  100.0
2020-11-01     NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN
2020-12-01     NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN
```

Now fill these values into `data` by rotating the columns:

```
>>> fillin.shift(-1, axis='columns').assign(Fall=fillin['Winter'])
Season      Winter  Spring  Summer  Fall
index                                   
2020-01-01     NaN     NaN     NaN  10.0
2020-02-01     NaN     NaN     NaN   NaN
2020-03-01     NaN     NaN     NaN   NaN
2020-04-01    40.0     NaN     NaN   NaN
2020-05-01     NaN     NaN     NaN   NaN
2020-06-01     NaN     NaN     NaN   NaN
2020-07-01     NaN    70.0     NaN   NaN
2020-08-01     NaN     NaN     NaN   NaN
2020-09-01     NaN     NaN     NaN   NaN
2020-10-01     NaN     NaN   100.0   NaN
2020-11-01     NaN     NaN     NaN   NaN
2020-12-01     NaN     NaN     NaN   NaN
>>> data.fillna(fillin.shift(-1, axis='columns').assign(Fall=fillin['Winter'])).plot(color=colors_map)
```

[image]

And here’s what this final result looks like with the new data in your post − my code is left unchanged:

[image]

Comment: very good solution but they are now disconnected

Comment: In the solution I shared in the body of the question, the lines are continuous

Comment: This is a simplified question; sales data is big and on a daily basis and as it is connected in each season, it should be connected between the seasons

Comment: Yes it wasn’t the easiest thing to do @AminBa but it works now.

Comment: @AminBa works just the same, the solution is generic. I reran my code with your new data and added the plot. You can put what you want in the column `Season` as long as it corresponds to the keys of `colors_map`.

Comment: But it is not the best solution as it is a time series and it is best not to put different parts of a time series into different columns. It is advisable to keep them in on column and add tags (such as `season`) to them

Comment: You have a time-dataframe now instead of a time-series: the index is still the same. Different columns allow the plot with different colors to be very easy. Other solutions are much harder and especially with the irregular data of your last update.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the reshaping is the way to go as it is used only for the plotting, but if you want a way to not reshape, you can do a `for` loop and get each season (of each year) and plot them independently on the same plot. Note that `loc` include both bounds, so you get the first element of Spring when selecting the Winter to be able to have a continuous plot for example.

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

# get index change season
season_changed = df.index[df['Season'].ne(df['Season'].shift())].tolist()

# Create the figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# iterate over each season - year
for start, end, season in zip(season_changed, 
                              season_changed[1:]+[df.index[-1]], 
                              df.loc[season_changed, 'Season']):
    df.loc[start:end, 'Sale'].plot(ax=ax, c=colors_map[season])

# define the legend
handles = [mpatches.Patch(color=val, label=key) 
           for key, val in colors_map.items()]
plt.legend(handles=handles, loc='best')

plt.plot()
```