# how to color data points based on some rules in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a signal, and I would like to color in red point which are too far from the mean of the signal. For example:

```
k=[12,11,12,12,20,10,12,0,12,10,11]
x2=np.arange(1,12,1)
plt.scatter(x2,k, label="signal")
plt.show()
```

I would like to color in red the data points 20 and 0, and I give them a special label like "warning".
I read [matplotlib: how to change data points color based on some variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881994/matplotlib-how-to-change-data-points-color-based-on-some-variable), but I am not sure how to apply it on my case

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want different labels, you need different plots.
Filter your data according to your formula.
In this case I took values which are more than 1.5 standard deviations away from the mean. In case you don't know, in `numpy` you can use boolean masks to index arrays and only take elemets where the mask is `True`. You can also easily flip the mask with the complement operator `~`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

k=np.array([12,11,12,12,20,10,12,0,12,10,11])
x2=np.arange(1,12,1)

# find out which parameters are more than 1.5*std away from mean
warning = np.abs(k-np.mean(k)) > 1.5*np.std(k)

# enable drawing of multiple graphs on one plot
plt.hold(True)

# draw some lines behind the scatter plots (using zorder)
plt.plot(x2, k, c='black', zorder=-1)

# scatter valid (not warning) points in blue (c='b')
plt.scatter(x2[~warning], k[~warning], label='signal', c='b')

# scatter warning points in red (c='r')
plt.scatter(x2[warning], k[warning], label='warning', c='r')

# draw the legend
plt.legend()

# show the figure
plt.show()
```

This is what you get:

[image]

Comment: swendel, what if i wanted to use a plot instead and not the scatter plot? but still want the warning point to be red?

Comment: Well, in that case the easiest solution would be to cheat a bit and add an extra plot that is rendered before the two scatter-plots. It *is* possible to have markers in different colors within one plot but getting the legend right might not be as easy. You probably could create a colorscheme and plot and annotate that but due to simplicity I'd prefer it this way. Once you want to have gradually color change indicating something like a severity, the colorschme thing might be better though.

Comment: i have a small issue, assuming that some entries with nan; how do i compute the mean taking into account  those nan?

Comment: @user3841581 use [np.nanmean](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html). There is also [np.nanstd](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.nanstd.html) ;)

Answer (score 7):

If you want just the colors, then try:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

k=[12,11,12,12,20,10,12,0,12,10,11]
x2=np.arange(1,12,1)

# Calculate an outlier limit (I chose 2 Standard deviations from the mean)
k_bar = np.mean(k)
outlier_limit = 2*np.std(k)
# Generate a colour vector
kcolors = ['red' if abs(value - k_bar) > outlier_limit else 'yellow' for value in k]

#Plot using the colour vector
plt.scatter(x2,k, label="signal", c = kcolors)
plt.show()
```

Comment: This only creates the color vector. It does not apply the actual color to the plot.

Comment: I removed my downvote. I don't think it was particularly harsh since the answer didn't actually answer the question, and the original code wasn't even valid Python. Now it's fine.

Comment: Fair comment. I was writing without an editor to test in!