# matplotlib plot (not scatter) color based on extra variable

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Good day,

I am trying to plot two arrays (`timesin` and `locations`) as a scatter of points. However, because `timesin` is a datetime object (of which I want time only), I find that I can only plot it properly using `pyplot.plot()`, not `pyplot.scatter()`. The issue arrises when I want to color the points on this plot with a third variable, `idx`. I know `pyplot.scatter()` is capable of doing this [quite easily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881994/matplotlib-how-to-change-data-points-color-based-on-some-variable), but I don't know how to do it with `pyplot.plot()`.

My excerpt of code:

```
import os
import tempfile
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
os.environ['MPLCONFIGDIR'] = tempfile.mkdtemp()

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

pp = PdfPages('output.pdf')
names = ['WestHall', 'Elevator', 'EastHall', 'MathLounge']
locations = np.arange(4)+1
plt.scatter(timesin, locations, c=idx, marker="o")
plt.xlabel("Time of day")
plt.ylabel("Location")
plt.yticks(np.arange(4)+1, names)
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
pp.savefig()
plt.close()
pp.close()
```

When I try this, I get an error, because it tries to interpret `idx` as rgba:

```
ValueError: to_rgba: Invalid rgba arg "[...]"
number in rbg sequence outside 0-1 range
```

How do I get it to interpret `idx` as conditional coloring without using `pyplot.scatter()`?

Thanks

**Update:**

As suggested by Hun, I actually can use `pyplot.scatter()` in this context by converting the datetime objects to numbers using matplotlibs dates library. Thus, figuring out how to use `pyplot.plot()` for conditional coloring was unnecessary.

Comment: You marked Hun's answer as the answer, but this doesn't answer your question. You should change your question to claim that Hun have answered it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier if you use plt.scatter(). But you need to convert the datetime to something scatter() can understand. There is a way to do it.

```
>>> dt # datetime numpy array
array(['2005-02-01', '2005-02-02', '2005-02-03', '2005-02-04'], dtype='datetime64[D]')

>>> dt.tolist() # need to be converted to list
[datetime.date(2005, 2, 1), datetime.date(2005, 2, 2), datetime.date(2005, 2, 3), datetime.date(2005, 2, 4)]

# convert the list to internal time information for matplotlib. But this is float.
>>> dt1 = matplotlib.dates.date2num(dt.tolist())
array([ 731978.,  731979.,  731980.,  731981.])
```

With this dt1 you can use plt.scatter()

Comment: Do they plot as numbers or as time?

Comment: I will be plotted as number. Since you know what those number means you can use x-axis label formatter to display datetime. You can use num2date() matplotlib function. Extra work but I don't see any other way of doing it for your case.

Comment: It seems date2num() and num2date() are made for this kind of purpose.

Comment: Would you mind adding an example of setting the x-axis by num2date() please?

Comment: Have you tried to look up the document on your own?

Comment: Well, I was able to figure it out. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is not possible to do this at once with matplotlib.pyplot.plot. However, here is my solution:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm

def scatterplot(x,y,prop):
    prop = cm.jet((prop-np.min(prop))/(np.max(prop)-np.min(prop)))
    ax = plt.gca()
    for i in xrange(len(x)):
        ax.plot(x[i],y[i],color=prop[i], marker='o')
    return

x = np.random.rand(100)
y = np.random.rand(100)
prop = -20+40*np.random.rand(100)

fig = plt.figure(1,figsize=(5,5))
ax  = fig.add_subplot(111)
scatterplot(x,y,prop)
plt.show()
```

which produces:

[image]

The only drawback of this approach is that if you have several particles, the process of walk through all of them can be relatively slow.

**EDIT (In response to @Nathan Goedeke's comment**:

I tried the same implementation but using a datetime object:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt

x = np.array([dt.datetime(2016, 10, 19, 10, 0, 0),
              dt.datetime(2016, 10, 19, 10, 0, 1),
              dt.datetime(2016, 10, 19, 10, 0, 2),
              dt.datetime(2016, 10, 19, 10, 0, 3)])

fig = plt.figure()
y = np.array([1, 3, 4, 2])
prop = np.array([2.,5.,3.,1.])
scatterplot(x,y,prop)
plt.show()
```

and it works as well.

Comment: Because my data to plot are datetime objects, I get an error when I try to implement this: 
`ValueError: ordinal must be >= 1`

Comment: Could you please write a minimum working example? I can not test it with your example...

Comment: You said that pyplot.plot worked for you, so I don't see why now you complain about this implementation, which actually uses pyplot.plot.

Comment: My example is the same as the code in my question only with the addition of `timesin` being an array of datetime objects.

Comment: I know pyplot.plot works, but for some reason when I tried your implementation I got a long traceback ending with `File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/dates.py", line 203, in _from_ordinalf
    dt = datetime.datetime.fromordinal(ix)
ValueError: ordinal must be >= 1`

Comment: I have tested it with datetime objects and edited my answer. It works as well, so your error seems to depend on your particular implementation within dates.py rather than a problem with my solution.

Comment: Thanks, but I found it was easier to convert to numbers and use Hun's suggestion