# Change colors of scatter plot points in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, colormap

I'm totally new to pythons graph visualization tools and I'm trying to show a scatter plot. The problem is that I can't seem to be able to obtain colors for my points different from grayscale values. This is my code:

```
cmap = cm.get_cmap('Spectral')
cat_length_1 = len(categories[cat1])
cat_length_2 = len(categories[cat2])
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
col = [0.123, 2598.35, 32.66, 669.3]
df.plot(cat1, cat2, kind='scatter', ax=ax, s=65, c =df[cat1] , linewidth=0, colormap=cmap)
plt.xticks(np.arange(cat_length_1 + 1), categories[cat1])
plt.yticks(np.arange(cat_length_2 + 1), categories[cat2])

if label_list != None:
    for k, v in df.iterrows():
        if k in label_list:
            ax.annotate(k, (v[cat1], v[cat2]), xytext=(rnd.randint(-30, 30), rnd.randint(-30, 30)), textcoords='offset points',
                    family='sans-serif', fontsize=12, color='darkslategrey',
                    arrowprops = dict(arrowstyle = '->', connectionstyle = 'arc3,rad=0'))

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

which provides this result:
[image]

I would like to color my points with all different colors based on the x axis value (but even random colors are ok).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `colormaps` take certain input values (e.g. `0-255` in `RGB`), so the `DataFrame` column that you are using to assign the colors needs to correspond to these input values, ie. you need to map your `categories` to any of the accepted color values. See [here](http://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Show_colormaps) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881994/matplotlib-how-to-change-data-points-color-based-on-some-variable) for more implementation detail.