# pandas: Using color in a scatter plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
--------------------------------------
|   field_0  |  field_1   | field_2  |
--------------------------------------
|     0      |   1.5      |  2.9     |
--------------------------------------
|     1      |   1.3      |  2.6     |
--------------------------------------
|       :                            |
--------------------------------------
|     1      |   2.1      |  3.2     |
--------------------------------------
|     0      |   1.1      |  2.1     |
--------------------------------------
```

I can create a scatter plot for field_1 vs. field_2 like below:

```
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')
my_df.plot(x='field_1', y='field_2', kind = 'scatter')
```

However, I am wondering is it possible to include field_0 in the plot? So when field_0 = 0, the point is blue; when field_1 = 1, the point is red.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [matplotlib: how to change data points color based on some variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881994/matplotlib-how-to-change-data-points-color-based-on-some-variable)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

you can do it this way:

```
col = df.field_0.map({0:'b', 1:'r'})
df.plot.scatter(x='field_1', y='field_2', c=col)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: It seems to work, but if you made the points bigger, it would be immediately visible!!

Comment: what about a legend?