# Is there any way to produce colored line in python using an array/list as the color mapping?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to create a 2D line plot in python using two arrays x and y. The line should have multiple colors based on a third array z and then add a colorbar next to the plot. The line colors between two point will have a smooth transition (linear interpolation) between the colors of the two points.

I have found this [How to change data points color based on some variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881994/how-to-change-data-points-color-based-on-some-variable)

However it only works with individual points and it does not create a line.

Furthermore I have found the multicolored line( https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html). This is somehow what I want but with the exception that I don't want to give the color value of a line segment. Instead I want to give the color value of a point (through the z array) and then the line should be colored automatically. Is there an easy way for this task?

Thanks

Comment: There is no automatic "color transition for the line between two colored points" function. You have to implement this yourself by creating a number of smaller line segments with gradual color change.

Comment: Scikit-image will give you a list of the points along a line. I guess you could work out the colours from your `z` array yourself... maybe?   https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.draw.html?highlight=line#skimage.draw.line