# Changing colors for data points in Matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am plotting an array `A` which has `len(A)=2`. I want to plot `A[0],A[1]` with separate colors on the same graph, not a single color as shown in the current output and also add legends for each `A[0],A[1]`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


A=np.array([[[0.02109   ],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.0201082 ],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.02055473],
       [0.02055797],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.02109   ]],
       
       [[0.02109   ],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.01127196],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.01573726],
       [0.01576968],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.02109   ]]])



plt.title("Line graph")
for i in range(0,len(A)):
    plt.plot(A[i], color="red", ls='', marker='o')
plt.xlabel('Node number')
plt.ylabel('IFT (mN/m)')
```

The current output is

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change data points color based on some variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881994/how-to-change-data-points-color-based-on-some-variable)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't :(

Comment: Can you use a scatter plot instead of a plot ? With this, you will be able to to it (and also you can remove your loop iteration if you create a dictionary of colors and legends before)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understating well your question, I would suggest to use `plot.scatter`, and also to remove the loop for plotting (which is faster in python if your `A` array is bigger), such as the following (`vec_x` is a vector with the corresponding index according to the shape of your matrix):

```py
vec_x = np.arange(np.shape(A)[1])
plt.scatter(vec_x, A[0], c='r', label='A[0]')
plt.scatter(vec_x, A[1], c='b', label='A[1]')
plt.legend()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to draw plots separately:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   

A=np.array([[[0.02109   ],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.0201082 ],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.02055473],
       [0.02055797],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.02109   ]],
       
       [[0.02109   ],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.01127196],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.01573726],
       [0.01576968],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.02109   ]]])



plt.title("Line graph")
for i in range(0,len(A[0])):
    plt.plot(i, A[0][i], color = 'red', ls='', marker='o')
    plt.plot(i, A[1][i], color = 'blue', ls='', marker='o')
plt.xlabel('Node number')
plt.ylabel('IFT (mN/m)')
plt.legend([1, 2])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: and about legend?

Comment: Sorry. I forgot. This time with legend

Comment: I want to have one color for ```A[0]```, another color for ```A[1]```. Not different colors for each point.

Comment: The same result as 'Only god knows' but with plot function

Answer (score 0):

You can make a list of color and assign it for A[i] in for loop. And for legend you need to add label, If you can also do this like the previous one but I did it like this `label= A[i]`
so final code should be:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

```
A=np.array([[[0.02109   ],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.0201082 ],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.02055473],
       [0.02055797],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.02109   ]],
       
       [[0.02109   ],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.01127196],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.01573726],
       [0.01576968],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.02109   ]]])


color_dot = ["blue", "red"]
plt.title("Line graph")
for i in range(0,len(A)):
    plt.plot(A[i], color= color_dot[i], ls='', marker='o', label= A[i])
    
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('Node number')
plt.ylabel('IFT (mN/m)')
```