# Plot points from Z vector at x,y coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two vectors, x & y:

```
x = [0,1,2,3,4]

y = [0,1,2,3]
```

and I have a vector z of length (x*y) e.g.

```
[5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]
```

The values in the vector z correspond to the coordinates `[(0,0),(0,1), (0,2),(0,3),(1,0), (1,1)...(4,3)]`

I want a plot where I can plot a point from z at the specified x,y coordinates.

So I want at coordinates (0,0) a value of 5. At (0,1) a value of 6, etc.

How can I do this? I've seen a lot of examples online where this is done as `plt.imshow`, or a heatmap. But nothing where I can essentially plot a scatter plot/line.

Comment: You can colour the scatter points based on the z values https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881994/how-to-change-data-points-color-based-on-some-variable

Comment: Or use z to set the marker size https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_demo2.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-scatter-demo2-py

Comment: Thanks @RuthC, but neither of these solutions are what I want. I can't do a scatter plot & then color/change marker size by z. I want the values in z to be plotted at the location (x,y) on the grid.

Comment: so what do you mean by "plot a value"?  If you do not represent the value by colour or size, what do you want to represent it by?

Comment: let me put it this way. x & y are not equal. As you can see, they are of different lengths. They are used to create a grid. At each point on the grid, one value of z should be plotted. does this make it clearer?

Comment: OK, so you need to expand x and y by using something like numpy.meshgrid (see @Noé Duruz answer below).  There is nothing to stop you having repeated x-values in a scatter plot.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [numpy meshgrid](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) and [maplotlib pcolormesh](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh.html) functions.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [0, 1, 2, 3]
z = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = np.array(z).reshape(X.shape)

plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

The idea is that `X` and `Y` contain the the coordinate in 2D such that, at the indexes `[i, j]`, the x-coordinate is given by `X[i, k]` and the same for the y-coordinate. Finally, `Z` is just the reshaped version of `z`, in a numpy array.

Finally, if you want a 3D plot, you can use the [plot_surface](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.plot_surface.html) function from matplotlib.

```py
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
plt.title('z as 3d height map')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me that what you are looking for is a point cloud plot. It is a plot where, as the name suggests, you produce a cloud of points with coordinates (x, y, z). However, most graphing libraries call it a scatter3d.

In matplotlib you can use: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/scatter3d.html

You may also have to restructure your arrays to expand the x and y arrays so that you have a one-to-one correspondence between x[i],y[i], and z[i]. Consider using the repeat and tile functions of numpy to do it.

Comment: thanks but this is for plotting along 3 axes. I just want to plot along 2 axes, and the values should be what is in the z vector (or array, if reshaped)

Answer (score 0):

Adapting Noé Duruz's solution to use scatter:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [0, 1, 2, 3]
z = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = np.array(z).reshape(X.shape)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(X, Y, c=Z)
plt.show()
```

[image]